# How to open macros from other databases - VBA, MS Access 2003

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've been tasked with creating an Access 2003 application that will act as a focal point for all other databases (6 in total). 
These 6 databases will each contain a macro used to build data bound for a table called `DispenseExport`.

Originally each of these databases had their own version of this table but now we have to have them all write to the one application - which I've affectionately codednamed **Omega**.

Omega will contain the `DispenseExport` table that all the others will write to. It will also be the database that calls the macros from the others to write to it.

So - what is the best way to accomplish this?

I already have a sample sub to call a macro from another database (and works) but the problem here is that it opens the database as any normal user would - Omega will sit on a server and needs to bypass this - by possibly using the **SHIFT-KEY** access method, if best?

How do I do that programmatically in VBA, assuming it's the best way to do so?

Here's what I have so far:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'Sub to call a macro from another database
Public Sub CallMacro()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

Debug.Print "Opening Macro"
    '/x tells the database to run the macro as soon as it is opened
    Call Shell("msaccess.exe C:\path-to-database\database.mdb /x mcrTestCall", 0)
Debug.Print "Completed Macro"

ErrHandler:

 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Create a message box with the error number and description
    MsgBox ("Sorry but error number " & Err.Number & " occurred; " & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
End If

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Still haven't found the answer but believe that I'm closing in. I need to find out how to emulate **HOLDING DOWN SHIFT** - any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will avoid shell call (Access 2007, also Access 2003?):

```
'
' variables:
'   strDbName: database filename
'   strMacro: macro name
'
Sub CallMacro()
'
  Dim strDbName, strMacro
  Dim objApp
'
  strDbName = "C:\path-to-database\database.mdb"
  strMacro = "mcrTestCall"
'
  Set objApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
'
  objApp.OpenCurrentDatabase strDbName
'
' Run Macro:
'
  objApp.DoCmd.RunMacro strMacro
'
  objApp.Quit
  Set objApp = Nothing
'
End Sub
```

To skip startup form or AutoExec, there is no simple solution, but we have a workaround in  http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0068.htm, by simulating the Shift key, using API.

Comment: This does work - it opens the database and runs the macro but the problem still persists - I still have to click 'Open' when the database opens - is there anyway to bypass that? Thanks

Comment: Do you click on 'Open' on a flag (popup) form to open a database?

Comment: There is no simple solution, please check http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0068.htm .

Answer (score 0):

There is a cleaner way to do this without opening the remote database. Build a query within that database that does what you want, then call it from the other database without ADO, DAO or opening it. Below is a link explaining how:
[Remote Queries](http://www.vb123.com.au/toolbox/02_accvb/remotequeries.htm)
Since links go away, the gist of it is this:
1. Build the query you want to call to return what you need in the other database
2. In the remote calling database, open a query without selecting a table (I use Query Design)
3. Right click on the query background and select 'Properties'
4. Replace the Database setting of (Current) with the full path to the database with the query
5. Build a query to call the original query as the datasource
6. Output the data by a "SELECT INTO" or DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, etc